# N vs L in South Asian Languages

Tags: historical-linguistics, pronunciation, indian-languages, laterals

A little background first. My parents were debating whether lemon in bengali was pronounced nebu or lebu. So, I decided to do some research into this and found that in many South Asian languages words that begin with the "L" sound have alternate pronunciations beginning with the "N" sound. For example, lemon can be pronounced as nimbu and limb in Hindi. How did this sort of duality develop historically?

Normally, sounds that are interchanged like this are very closely related. For example, fish in English is related to the the Latin piscus. "F" is closely related to "P". How is "N" closely related to "L"?

Comment: In modern Thai, `l` and `r` as the final consonant (at the end of the syllable) uniformly becomes `n`.

Comment: Related: [What about the sound change initial n -> initial l?](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/1642)

Comment: In some dialects of Northern Vietnamese there are also merges of N and L

Comment: There is also a L-N merger which merges to N instead of L in South Korean (alright, the L is actually an alveolar flap, but whatever)

Comment: in [Southern Chinese languages there's a similar phenomenon](https://www.quora.com/Why-do-many-Asian-people-have-trouble-with-and-mix-up-the-letters-R-and-L/answer/Derek-Zech?share=2325c78d&srid=teex), like Cantonese [你 can be pronounced as either *nei* or *lei*](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/phorum/read.php?1,56835,56842)

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: Some of that comes through even to Mandarin. I know there's a couple of examples but the one I can think of is that English/Italian *latte* came to Mandarin through a Southern Chinese language after the *l* had transformed to *n* leaving us with *ná tiě*.

Answer (score 6):

There is an acoustic similarity between *n* and *l*, which have anti-resonances; this makes the consonants sound similar. This is a reasonable common sound change.

Comment: Any references for this phenomenon would be kindly appreciated.